# How to remove the border around (UITableView) grouped textfields

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

The cells of my UITableView are grouped text fields. When I run my code on the emulator, I get this:

[image: Grouped text fields and button]

As you can see there is a gray area around the text fields while the background of the UITableView and the button is white. Is it possible to remove, or make invisible, the gray border (not the separator or the frame but the area) around the grouped cells? If so, how can I do that?

Update: Background color is working on iPhone but not on iPad. I'm working on iPad.

**I fixed the problem.** Solution:

```
UIView *clearView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[myTableView bounds]];
clearView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
myTableView.backgroundView = clearView;
[clearView release];
```

Since setting the background on the xib file is not working, I did it programatically. Here, `myTableView` is the tableView object on the xib. As you can see, I replaced the background view with a view that has a clear color (transparent). The desired effect is achieved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the table view's background colour you can do it in the nib

[image]

Making the background colour clear just means you have to be aware of what is behind the table - as you will then see that!

If you mean the gray lined border You have to do it in code.. So in say the viewDidLoad method of the table view's owning class.

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: No, not the separator. As you can see in the image, there is a roundrect, which is the UITableView, whose cells are composed of text fields. Now around this round rect is a gray area. I want to remove or hide that area.

Comment: I've already tried that but it doesn't seem to work. I expected that the the grayish area will become white or invisible but nothing seem to happen.

Comment: Ok change the background colour to RED - see if RED makes an appearance when you execute the app. If it does, then the gray you are seeing is behind the tableview, either in the same xib as the table view or in a parent view controller.

Comment: If the style is Grouped, it does not change to red. However, if it is plain, the background color is applied. So, I think it has something to do with them being grouped.

Comment: I have a grouped table view here and it does not behave as you described. It shows whichever background colour I choose. I dunno man - good luck. I think you need to start a new question though as we are now way beyond your original one.

Comment: Mine's 4.3. I'm not sure if this problem is really related to Xcode. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I failed to mention, I am doing this on iPad. I tested this on iPhone and found out that it is working perfectly.

Comment: Hmmm that is very odd. I definitely think you need to (mark me up) start a new question now that you have 'qualified' what is going on to such a degree you should be able to 1. tag the question better and 2. describe all your findings to date.

Answer (score 1):

Set the background color of the table view to clear color.

Like this

```
myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

myTableView.opaque = NO;
myTableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Comment: This is not working on iPad but it is totally working on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your table as following to get plain tableview.

```
yourTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 460) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Comment: I don't need to convert it to plain style since I need it to be grouped.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah friends, Nothing to do extra, just set your table view background to nil.

```
yourTableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Enjoy :)